# Community to have some pages publicly available, others require login and redirect to original page from which the login page was called after login

Tags: visualforce, customer-community, lightning-community

We have a community which we want to have some pages which are to be publicly accessible and some which requires login.

Is there a way to specify which pages require login and which require are viewable by all?

I also have bunch of VF pages where i am checking if the user is Guest then redirect to login page and needs to return to the page which its called from

```
public PageReference checkLogin_FP() {
    System.debug('UserInfo.getUserType() ' +UserInfo.getUserType());
   System.debug('currenturl' + ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
if (UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Guest') {
    PageReference loginPage = Page.CommunitiesLogin;
    String idval = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    String Starturl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('/apex/backgroundCheckConsents?id='+idval, 'UTF-8');
    loginPage.getParameters().put('startURL', Starturl);
    loginPage.setRedirect(true);

    return loginPage;
} else {

}

return null;
}
```

But this code doesnt redirect to the page specified in the login url but takes to the landing page specified in the sites. The template used is the sites one and not the communities template.

What is the best way to redirect the user back to the page they orignated from before they were redirected to the login page.

The use case would be someone applying for a job. The job details would be on the sites page but the actual application would be on the community. Once they login they need to go the application page. I can call the application page from public page but if they are not logged in it would redirect to login page and once logged in redirect to the application page

Thanks

Comment: You should add the pages which needs to be publicly available to the force.com sites, with that you do not need the check for redirection. The other pages part of community not added to force.com sites would still require authentication.

Comment: Thanks!! that makes sense, but i need to redirect to a dynamic url after they login. the use case would be someone applying for a job. The job details would be on the sites page but the actual application would be on the community. Once they login they need to go the application page. I can call the application page from public page but if they are not logged in it would redirect to login page and once logged in redirect to the application page

Comment: You could [override the default home/landing page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_community_home.htm&type=5)) of communities with your application page (do not add this page on public force.com sites). And in your force.com site, you can configure `Authorization Required Page (401)` with your custom login page. With all these configuration I think you can chive your requirement.

Comment: I am not sure pushing putting the application page as the landing page would be a right idea because everytime someone logs in it would get to this page and people would login for various other purposes as well